# Equivalence of derivation of Majorana fermions

Tags: superconductivity, majorana-fermions

Perhaps is this a stupid question but I have really no answer. To prove the emergence of Majorana bound states I search zero-energy solution of the Bogoliubov - de Gennes equation

$$
H\Psi\left(x\right) = \left[\left(\frac{-\hbar^{2}}{2m}\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}} - \mu\right)\tau_{z} + B\sigma_{x} + \alpha k\sigma_{y}\tau_{z} + \Delta\tau_{x}\right]\Psi\left(x\right) = 0
$$

If we have a Majorana bound state, then the Nambu spinor is invariant under particle-hole transformation. This in only true for a magnetic field $B > \sqrt{\Delta^{2} + \mu^{2}}$.

If I now calculate

$$
H\Psi\left(k\right) = \left[\left(\frac{\hbar^{2}k^{2}}{2m} - \mu\right)\tau_{z} + B\sigma_{x} + \alpha k\sigma_{y}\tau_{z} + \Delta\tau_{x}\right]\Psi\left(k\right) = 0
$$

I obtain the condition that $\Psi\left(k\right)$ is invariant under particle-hole transformation if $1 = \frac{-\mu + \sqrt{\Delta^{2} + \mu^{2}}}{\Delta}$ and $k = 0$.

Is there a general reason why the results for different representations of $\Psi$ are so different? I would say both representations should give the same result, but the condition $\Psi\left(k\right)$ and can not be true.

Comment: Could you perhaps edit the question so that it becomes clearer that you are talking about superconductors, and give a *minimal context*? Were it not for the tag "superconductivity", I would have no idea what physical situation you are looking at (and why you are talking about a "magnetic field).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but it is clear that there is no representation of the Majorana-mode in the momentum-space. Indeed, expanding in Fourier basis would lead to $\Psi\sim\exp(ikx)$ whereas the Majorana wave function is a real decaying exponential. So in short the Majorana mode must be the solution of a differential equation. Note that $k$ in your first equation must read $-i\nabla$ for the same reason.

Comment: Also, the Majorana only exists at the edge between different space region characterised by different topological number. If I trust your criterion, I'd say that the unpaired Majorana mode exists around the point $B_{c}=\sqrt{\Delta^{2}+\mu^{2}}$ between the sector with $B>B_{c}$ and the sector with $B<B_{c}$. Please check http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1145 for more details of the calculation.

Comment: But why must the Nambu spinor (this is what you mean with Majorana wave function?) be real? For Majorana fermions the Nambu spinor must statisfy $\left(u,v\right) = \left(v^\star, u^\star\right)$. In principle $u$ and $v$ can be complex.